# gcc linker produces unexpected so (clang is fine)

Tags: c, gcc, linker, clang, ldd

A program is linked properly with clang, but not with gcc:

```
% CC=clang make
clang -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -llua5.1 -shared -fPIC -o mk_lua.so mk_lua.c
% ldd mk_lua.so 
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4effe000)
   liblua5.1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so.0 (0x00007fa94b316000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa94af51000)
   libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa94ac4a000)
   libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa94aa46000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa94b752000)
```

GCC gives different results (of course, leads to a broken shared library).

```
% CC=gcc make
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -llua5.1 -shared -fPIC -o mk_lua.so mk_lua.c
% ldd mk_lua.so 
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcf3fe000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe2e3e06000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe2e43d9000)
```

- gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6)
- Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)

Linker options are identical. What is going on here?

Full source is [here](https://github.com/Motiejus/makelua).

Comment: Try GCC 5, it is not released, but might fix this bug already. If not, please file a bug.

Comment: Nature of the problem (read: trivial) makes me believe this is actually my problem, not GCC's. This looks too simple to be a bug in GCC.

Comment: What if you move your `-llua5.1` switch to the end of the command line? GCC can sometimes be funny about the order and position of them.

Comment: @slugonamission that's right, please this comment and answer so I can upvote it.